# How can schroot works with aufs

Tags: chroot, aufs, schroot

I'm using `schroot` with `aufs`.  Currently, my conf file under `\etc\schroot\chroot.d` looks like

```
[trusty_chrome]
description=Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty running Chrome and Adobe Flash
directory=/srv/chroot/trusty_chrome
personality=linux
...
union-type=aufs
union-mount-options=br:/srv/chroot/trusty_chrome.aufs=rw:/srv/chroot/base/trusty_amd64=ro
```

Basically, the overlay and underlay directory is specified in the mount option.  While `man schroot.conf` hints that they could also be determined by keys `union-overlay-directory` and `union-underlay-directory`, while I can not enter chroot properly with these options. More precisely, if I use the following conf,

```
[trusty_chrome]
description=Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty running Chrome and Adobe Flash
directory=/srv/chroot/trusty_chrome
personality=linux
...
union-type=aufs
union-overlay-directory=/srv/chroot/trusty_chrome.aufs
union-underlay-directory=/srv/chroot/base/trusty_amd64
```

I'll encounter errors

```
E: 20copyfiles: cp: cannot create regular file '/var/lib/schroot/mount/trusty_chrome-cb1db93d-c07c-4c2d-bef2-f5025358c2b3/etc/resolv.conf': No such file or directory
E: trusty_chrome-cb1db93d-c07c-4c2d-bef2-f5025358c2b3: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start
```

when try to enter this chroot. So the question is, how could I configure schroot using aufs by keys `union-overlay-directory` and `union-underlay-directory`.

Moreover, when I list all chroot managed

```
$ schroot -l
chroot:trusty_chrome
...
source:trusty_chrome
...
```

I'll find two entries for each chroot using aufs.  Is `source:blabla` a chroot?  I can't enter them by schroot.

I'm using `schroot (Debian sbuild) 1.6.10 (04 May 2014)` in Ubuntu 14.10.